# How can I install python on windows 11?

Tags: python, installation, administrator

I want to install the latest version of python but "use admin privileges when installing py.exe" option is off and I do not know how to fix it.

I tried Administrator terminal and typed: Enable-LocalUser -Name “Administrator”
But nothing changed.[here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ1q3.png)

Comment: Your image seems to show that option is **on** and cannot be switched off. Did you try clicking on `Install Now`?

Comment: That looks fine. I recommend checking the "Add python.exe to PATH" checkbox and then just click "Install Now"

Comment: Well quamrana....NO I did not try install now because I thought If I do it it is not gonna work.

Comment: Yes, I think that all the time. But, then I check the evidence. If you know that a program is going to need admin privileges, then you can usually right-click and `Run as administrator`.

Comment: THANK YOU FRIENDS. IT IS INSTALLED FINE :)

Answer (score 0):

When administration privilege is off, this cripples you in some degree but take heart, you can always visit Microsoft Store and install the latest version of python. This is an easy way to bypass the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to worry about that since it is been enabled by default you can go along with it and install it.

 If that realy worries you install 3.11 and wait till the 3.11.4 update. the latest isnt the gratest.